# Is my controller broken?

Tags: xbox-360, halo-4, call-of-duty-black-ops-3

Whenever I play first person shooters, I push the left stick up, and my gun shoots. Rt is to walk. But when I go to my controls, it is set to default, which is left stick to move, and Rt is shoot. Is it the game, or my controller?

Comment: What other games use the Lt?  If you know what it's supposed to do, you can test if it does the same thing by wiggling the left analog stick.

Comment: Again, does it do that in other games?  This is an easy thing to test.  If it does, it's your controller.  If it doesn't, there's something in your games.

Comment: @Frank It goes away when I press Rt, but comes back after 5 seconds. The controller is 3 days old.

Comment: @Frank Cod and halo 4 are the only first persons I have, but it doesn't do that to gears or gta

Answer (score 1):

Is your controler an OEM or aftermarket as some aftermarket controllers allow you remap your buttons (ex. Have RT set to jump {A} and A set to shoot  {RT}) if it is an aftermarket I would suggest getting the booklet it came with and finding out if you can remap the controls.